# Internationalization English & Indian languages

Tags: internationalization

I am working on a Java application primarily on English but also hope to support Indian languages like Hindi, Telugu and Gujarati. I am wondering what can be a good strategy for this.

I have seen I18N projects in Latin script based languages but Hindi uses Devanagri script so it's a little more complicated.

Has anyone done anything close to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, the scripts and languages you mentioned are not necessary very common in programming. Since you didn't mention whether it will be desktop or web application, it will be quite hard to give you any advice apart from use latest Java (7) and [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) (49.1 or even 50M2) version.
That's because this releases support newer version of the Unicode Standard, and it will play a role here.

BTW. You might want to know, that [the Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/) is working on better support for Indian scripts. Therefore developing applications with this languages in mind will be easier in the future, for now you will probably struggle a bit.

Comment: Hey Pawel, it is a web application but I don't understand how using the latest Java helps. There is nothing special mentioned in the release that it supports these Indian languages better.

Comment: @Vineet: Actually, there is something special. Something special is support for Unicode v 6.0. And AFAIK it makes a huge difference for this languages. BTW. release notes on Java 7 does not cover changes in I18n support too well. The information are pretty sparse, whereas changes are big.